# smart capture javascript validation

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, smart-capture

I tried to do validation using Javascript on smart capture.
When I submit the form it does not seem that the function is running.

My code:

Form tag:

```
<form id="myId" class="smartcapture-content-wrapper fuelux" onsubmit="return valid();" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Javascript function:

```
<script>
function valid() {
    if(SOME IF)
    {
        return false;   
    }
    return true;

}
</script>
```

How can I make it work?

Is there another way to do the validation?

Comment: Is the above JavaScript code the actual code that you're using or has it been truncated for brevity? The online documentation has an example you can follow: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_validate_fields_in_a_smart_capture_form_with_javascript.htm&type=5

Comment: This Javascript code is abbreviated for example.

Comment: @DanielRomano Do you see any errors in the JS using Google a chrome extension developer tools?